# Magento 2 get custom customer attribute displayed value

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, customer-attribute

I'm using the module Amasty's customer Attributes to create custom customer attributes,
I like to get custom attribute displayed value but i got the option value.
I like to get the value in data-title attribute
[image]

I tried this

```
  if ($customAttribute = $customer->getCustomAttribute('custom_value')){
            $regrouper = $customAttribute->getValue();
            
            var_dump(regrouper);exit; //it returns 615 instead of 'Ok'
            
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an ugly way of doing it but having been struggling myself doing it I ended up with this workaround creating this method that will take as parameter the getValue return.

If you found a better way of doing thing, please share :)

```
/**
 * TODO Rework method with collection or repository ?
 * @param $option_id
 * @return string
 */
public function getAttributeValueLabel($option_id){
    $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
    $select = $connection->select()
        ->from(
            ['ol' => 'eav_attribute_option_value'],
            ['value']
        )
        ->where('option_id = ?',$option_id);
    return $connection->fetchOne($select);
}
```

Comment: How to get option id?

Comment: As I said the option_id should match the value that is already returned by your custom attribute getValue 615 is actually the option id 615. You can pre check the request doing it by hand `select * from eav_attribute_option_value where option_id = 615` and you should be able to retrieve the label data in the result request.

Comment: I contacted Amasty, i'm waiting for their answer, otherwise i tested you query and it returns the right result

Comment: Glad to hear it's working for you. It's not really amasty specific, the issue would be the same with every custom attribues. Now may be the people from amasty will came out with a better solution or even the right way of doing things. Hope !